# WebDriverBackedSelenium FireFoxDriver not checking checkboxes

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, web-testing

I've searched everywhere and it seems I'm the only one having this issue. When trying to click on a checkbox with firefoxdriver using webdriverbackedselenium. Most of the time it won't click. The page source says I'm getting the ID properly, when I use ChromeDriver and IEDriver it works fine. Anyone have any ideas as to what my problem could be?

example:

```
selenium.click("id=someID");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue I've run into with WebDriver, and I've seen it affect radio buttons as well, and not just on Firefox - the only thing I've been able to do is put it in a **do while** loop and assert the checked state (pseudo-code):

```
do
{
  checkElement(element);
}
while (elementIsChecked(element) != desiredState);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, the problem with this is I often get an infinite loop. It appears to be something to do with scrolling, if I inject javascript that scrolls the page to a certain point it works...sometimes.

Comment: Try clicking on the element instead, that usually will respect the viewport and scroll to the item in question.